# Alarm manager not work on emulator android 11

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager

I create an alarm and its work on android studio emulator with android (7) api 25

But in Android studio Emulator with **Android (11) Api 30** and above **alarms not work!** where is the problem?

- compileSdk 30
- minSdk 21
- targetSdk 30

```kotlin
val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
val intent = Intent(applicationContext, ReminderAlarmActivity::class.java)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext, 123456, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14)
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20)

val ac = AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
alarmManager.setAlarmClock(ac, pendingIntent)
```

Comment: Try changing flags argument to `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE`

Comment: @TomBerghuis Still not work!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add permission to the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
```

Comment: I added before, and has no effect.

Comment: @morteza moradi try to use setAlarmExact but check calendar time in ms and the current time, if the current time more then add a day to calendar